# Row height does not work when wrapping text (xlsxwriter)

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Code:

```
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Тест')
worksheet.set_row(0, 15)
worksheet.write(0, 0, 'Тело запроса с названиями товаров к которым необходимо найти верную модель',
                workbook.add_format({'text_wrap': True}))
workbook.close()
```

Result:
[image: result]

I tried setting the line height below the `write`, as well as using `set_default_row` - it doesn't work

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? can you show example of the wanted outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature of Excel runtime where it automatically adjusts the row height for wrapped text if the row height hasn't been adjusted manually.

In you case you **do** adjust the row height manually but to the default row height so it isn't distinguishable from an un-modified row height.

If you set the row height to any other value you will see that it works as expected:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Test')
worksheet.set_row(0, 16)
worksheet.write(0, 0, 'Тело запроса с названиями товаров к которым необходимо найти верную модель',
                workbook.add_format({'text_wrap': True}))
workbook.close()
```

[image: screenshot]

If you want to avoid the automatic row height feature and still maintain the default row height you can use a value that is slightly different from 15 but will get truncated to 15 by Excel like 15.001

```py
worksheet.set_row(0, 15.001)
```